# How to discard throwaway @Injected beans?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, idioms

My `ExampleBean` needs information from `UsefulBean1` only at creation time. So I can discard the `UsefulBean1` instance after getting the information I want.

```java
@ManagedBean
public class ExampleBean {

   private int value;

   @Inject
   public void setUseful(UsefulBean usefulBean){
        this.value = usefulBean.getValue();
        //bye, bye usefulBean. see ya.
   }
}
```

But what about my `ExampleBean2`, that needs, at creation time, combined information from `UsefulBean1`and `UsefulBean2`?

I know I can get them `@Injected` and combine the information on a `@PostConstruct` method:

```java
@ManagedBean
public class ExampleBean2 {

   private int value;

   @Inject 
   private UsefulBean1 usefulBean1;

   @Inject 
   private UsefulBean2 usefulBean2;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init(){
        this.value = this.usefulBean1.getValue() + this.usefulBean2.getValue();
        //from this point on, the usefulBeans fields are useless...
        this.usefulBean1 = null;
        this.usefulBean2 = null;

   }
}
```

But it annoys me a bit that I keep these two no-longer-necessary fields (`this.usefulBean1` and `this.usefulBean2`).

I have tried a multi-parameter set method, to no avail.

This is surely nothing breaking anything or wasting resources. But the code, IMHO, would just be more clear without fields working as temporary throwaway variables.

Is there a away to initialize a CDI bean with data from multiple other beans, without the need to set them as fields?

Comment: Use constructor injection. Always use constructor injection. Both setter and field injection are a hangover from another, much worse, time. Don't use them. Don't even think about using them. Not only does constructor injection give you testable, immutable objects; it also completely solves your problem.

Comment: @BoristheSpider construtor injection would prevent the bean to be proxied, since the specs as for a no-args non-private constructor: https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#unproxyable

Comment: Then don't use that awful CDI framework. DI frameworks should help you to write good code not force you to write untestable unmaintainable nonsense - that's the exact opposite of the intent of the Inversion of Control pattern.

Comment: That's in the SPEC. Can't blame the framework.

Answer (score 0):

(First, `@ManagedBean` has nothing to do with CDI.  It should not be used.)

(Second, always think about lifespans ("scopes"): how long should each bean live?  For this example I'll pretend that you want `ExampleBean2` to be the only such bean in your application, so I'll mark it with `@ApplicationScoped` (some of your comments above reference proxying so this is a reasonable guess).  You could annotate it with, for example, `@RequestScoped` or `@Dependent` or some other scope instead.  If you don't annotate it with any scope annotation, then it will behave exactly as if you had annotated it with `@Dependent`.)

Like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ExampleBean2 {

  private final int value;

  /**
   * @deprecated To be used only by the CDI framework, not end users.
   */
  @Deprecated
  protected ExampleBean2() {
    super();
  }

  @Inject
  public ExampleBean2(final UsefulBean1 usefulBean1, final UsefulBean2 usefulBean2) {
    super();
    this.value = this.usefulBean1.getValue() + this.usefulBean2.getValue();
  }

}
```